# How to graph CSV files using mathplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, graph

I need some help plotting these data points from [this](http://data.un.org/_Docs/SYB/PDFs/SYB62_154_201906_Health%20Personnel.pdf) .csv file into a line graph.

I'm trying to plot the United States and Vietnam's # of health personnel over the years 2005, 2010, 2015, and 2016. So, the x values will be 2005, 2010, 2015, 2016, and the y values will be # of personnel.

Problem is, I don't know where to start! I'm not quite sure how to specify what points of data I want to extract when the .csv files are so huge. I'm usually used to .csv files containing very simple data:

```
 0, 1
 1, 1
 2, 3
 3, 5
 4, 7
 5, 8
```

The actual .csv file I'm trying to work with can be accessed [here](http://data.un.org/_Docs/SYB/CSV/SYB62_154_201906_Health%20Personnel.csv).

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: plt.plot takes x and y points to make a line

Comment: the file is not really good for extracting data from it

Answer (score 1):

```py
url = "http://data.un.org/_Docs/SYB/CSV/SYB62_154_201906_Health%20Personnel.csv"

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=1)

# Some data tidying
data['Value'] = data['Value'].str.replace(',', "").astype(float)
data = data.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1': "Country"})

def plot_country_occupation(country, occupation):
    data[
        ~data['Series'].str.contains('(per 1000 population)')
        & (data['Country'] == country)
        & (data['Series'].str.contains(occupation))
    ].plot(x='Year', y='Value', title=" - ".join([country, occupation]))
```

With the function, you can specify the country and the occupation.

```py
plot_country_occupation('Viet Nam', 'Physicians')
```

[image: Vietnam Physicians]

```py
plot_country_occupation('United States of America', 'Pharmacists')
```

[image: US Pharmacists]

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! Problem is, I'm running VS code, and I want to generate these files within the folder that the script is running in. I can't find the graphs anywhere when I try this-- any advice?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to save the plot images as files? Probably you have to use [savefig](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)

Comment: Ideally the image should show up on the program-- like what plt.show() would do. Additionally, is there any advice you can give me if I'm trying to just make a specific graph show up-- without the function?

Comment: Say I run the program, what should occur is the graph of both Vietnam and the US on one line graph appear on a window. Thanks for taking the time to help me by the way!

Comment: > Ideally the image should show up on the program-- like what plt.show() would do.
---
I would have advised to use `plt.show`. What's the problem with it?

Comment: For overlaying the plots on top of each other, you might want to generate the plots on the same axis. That is, 1) `fig, axis = plt.subplots(1, 1)` and then 2) pass `ax=axis` in the `plot` method.

Comment: It is hard to advise from here. You might search SO for a solution or generate a separate issue for that.